# Android Studio Gradle Sync failed with company proxy: unable to find valid certification path

Tags: android, maven, gradle, https, proxy

I need your help. I have to make an Android app in a company and have some problems to run and configure Android Studio. The network uses a proxy (from Zscaler) and I can't synchronize project from Gradle scripts.

The administrator have given to me the proxy address and on check connection settings, connection is successful with the 2 download domains from the `build.gradle` scripts. But it doesn't work on Gradle sync.

THE FOLLOWING ERRORS:
With normal case on `build.gradle`:

> - Could not GET: "https://dl.google.com.dl/android/maven2/"
> - Could not GET: "https://jcenter.bintray.com/
>
> With http on maven blocks: Could not GET (From jcenter binary with
>   http)
>
> Unable to find valid certification path.

I have also import manually certificates from the company, but it doesn't work.
You can look on images to show you my configuration I have tried, and it doesn't work.

Images links here:

1. https://ibb.co/bJxT9d
2. https://ibb.co/e7wMUd
3. https://ibb.co/inro9d
4. https://ibb.co/gic6vJ
5. https://ibb.co/eS04hy
6. https://ibb.co/bOfLNy

Help me please, it's extremely important. I can't do the objectives otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject your companies proxy cert into the cacerts keystore of the java attempting to download files.  This may be either the OpenJDK version that is supplied with your Android Studio or the one being used by the operating system.

Keytool is located in /jre/bin

The "cacerts" file is located in /jre/lib/security

Run the following

```
keytool -importcert -file <path to cert> -keystore <path to cacerts>
-alias <anything>
```

You'll be prompted for the password, default is "changeit"

You'll then be asked if you trust the cert, type yes.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I have run the keytool on terminal inside key tool path. I have 2 certificates to install manually and all JREs must to target certificates. A detailed solution is here: http://andreyaleev.com/2018/01/14/setup-proxy-in-android-studio/

Comment: If you have 2 certificates, you have to run 2 lines of keytool. For this operation to solve proxy problem, I have run 7 lines.

Comment: Done. But it's not finished now. The last problem is about Internet connection on emulators. I can't with proxy settings connect to Internet in the emulator.

Comment: Related question about emulator here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964820/android-studio-no-internet-connection-on-emulator-with-company-proxy

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm on Mac with `zscaler` proxy using Android studio `Electric Eel`.

**Step 1: Download Root CA**

I had already the certificate installed in my machine so I went in `Keychain Access`, then `System Roots`, right click on the zscaler cert and `exported` in `Desktop`.

At this point, depending on how you saved the cert you should have something similar to:

```
tree ~/Desktop
- Zscaler-Root-CA.cert
```

**Step 2: import cert**

As mentioned before:

```
keytool -import -trustcacert -file ~/Desktop/Zscaler-Root-CA.cert -alias custom-Root-CA -keystore /Application/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

Use password `changeit`.

**Step 3: close and restart android studio**

Without restart it didn't work. After the restart `gradle` downloaded automatically and built the app.

Answer (score 0):

The official solution, with keytool (3 lines to execute at least):
On command line (cmd, terminal), open the directory /jre/bin, commands to write:
`keytool -import -alias <alias> -file <certificate_path .crt or .cer> -keystore ../jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Each Java part (JRE) must to have certificates added with keytool (Java, Android Studio,...), the 2 lines must to be executed:
`keytool -import -alias <alias> -keystore <path_to>\system\tasks\cacerts -file <certificate_path .crt or .cer>`

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <path_to>\system\tasks\cacerts -destkeystore "<path_to>\Java\<jre_path_name>\lib\security\cacerts"`

Reboot the system after.

I remember the source: http://andreyaleev.com/2018/01/14/setup-proxy-in-android-studio/