# No Internet connection on emulator with company proxy

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, http-proxy

I have to ask for the last problem I've encountered on Android Studio. After finishing successfully the IDE configuration with the Zscaler proxy certificates (with keytool), I can't have Internet connection inside the Android Emulator.

I have put in Emulator proxy settings IP, port (given by the administrators from the company Information System Committee of the company) and my credentials for proxy authentication, but it doesn't work, the connection is refused:

[Emulator settings view + connection refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrU5t.png)

I have tried with API 23, 25, 27 and 28.

If this configuration only doesn't works, how to solve the problem?
I have also 2 .crt files for certificates, should it be the solution to fix it?

If yes, would you tell me how to put the certificates inside the Android Emulator from the company computer? Which path, please.

I must have an Internet connection on an emulator to make the app with APIs.

Help me, please.

Comment: It's related to my previous problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930416/android-studio-gradle-sync-failed-with-company-proxy-unable-to-find-valid-certi/50951268#50951268

Comment: Note: I have now imported from the Android Studio's Device File Explorer the certificates files, but it doesn't work. Any suggestion to solve that an have access to Internet ?

Comment: Apparently, emulator proxy settings declines identifiers like user@company.domain.

Answer (score 0):

No possible way now. I have checked HTTP/HTTPS requests, I got connection refused with HTTPS, code 301 with HTTP (it redirects to the company gateway firewall and the network system revokes the access).

I have contacted the administrators of my company Information System Commitee, and they can't do something. I have given the IP of the concerned computer but it depends now of the Internet Security provider (Zscaler). They have send a help message to the support to grant the Internet access to my AVDs.

I hope it will be solved very soon.

Comment: Conclusion: I can't bypass myself with certificates and proxy configuration.

Comment: Any update on this? I am in the exact same situation.